# Solr: How to get matched substring from solr field?

Tags: solr, solr4

Suppose all documents has a field content and all content field has 1000 characters. Now if i search for "news" keyword in all documents content field, it should give me a sub strings of 150 characters with a matched keyword in it. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Highlighting** which generates the search result fragments which also includes the user query.
The fragments are included in a special section of the response (the highlighting section).
Below is the sample query.

```
localhost:8983/solr/mydocs/select?q=news&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.fragsize=150
```

#### Highlighting Params

```
hl=true          #Enable Highlighting  
hl.fl=content    #Specifies a list of fields to highlight
hl.fragsize=150  #Specifies the size, in characters, of fragments to consider for highlighting
```

Comment: For more information on highlighting https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting

Comment: How can i do this, if the highlighting array is empty than show 150 characters from original content in the highlighting array?

Comment: To get snippets anyway, when there are none with highlights, set f.content.hl.alternateField=content (note, if the content field is empty, this won't help)